# How to resize a UIModalPresentationFormSheet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am trying to display a modal view controller as a UIPresentationFormSheet. The view appears, but I can't seem to resize it. My XIB has the proper height & width, but it seems to get overridden when I call it like this:

```
composeTweetController = [[ComposeTweet alloc] initWithNibName:@"ComposeTweet" bundle:nil];
composeTweetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:composeTweetController animated:TRUE];
```

Any thoughts? I am using the iPhone SDK 3.2 beta 4

Comment: The beta is under NDA, so I doubt you'll get many answers here. I recommend using Apple's SDK 3.2 Beta forums at http://devforums.apple.com

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You are able to adjust the frame of a modal view after presenting it:

**Tested in iOS 5.1 - 7.1**

```
MyModalViewController *targetController = [[[MyModalViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
targetController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;  //transition shouldn't matter
[self presentViewController:targetController animated:YES completion:nil];

if(floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1){
     targetController.view.superview.frame = CGRectInset(targetController.view.superview.frame, 100, 50);
}else{
     targetController.view.frame = CGRectInset(targetController.view.frame, 100, 50);
     targetController.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: YES! Thanks! The trick seems to be to resize it after presenting it.

Comment: It works also for me on iPad, but...
If I rotate the device, the view is not centered

Comment: @MauroDelrio To make it work correctly from landscape you need to flip the center coordinates.

ex: 
CGPoint center = self.view.center;
targetController.view.superview.center = {isPortrait} ? center : CGPointMake(center.y, center.x);

Comment: Careful for this approach, it causes some distortion in the view controller's views as a result of the scaling.

Comment: This approach works for resizing, but messed up subview autoresizing from IB, because resizing is done after view is presented.  I have another solution that works below.

Comment: If you get blurring change the size by 1 pixel, the pixel sizes must be even in both dimensions. If its odd, when its centered it halfs the odd pixel and you get blur.

Comment: @bdrober, thanks for your solution, it was helpful. BTW, you are missing a "C" in the last line of your solution, "GPointMake" needs to be "CGPointMake".

Comment: Nice solution. I prefer changing the bounds like so `targetController.view.superview.frame = CGRectInset(targetController.view.superview.frame, 110, 70);`

Comment: If I'm using a storyboard, does the above solution require that I not have a segue wired up to my modal from the view controller that calls it? Does this have to all be in code?

Comment: Also, if someone that has this working could spin up a sample project, I'd be forever in your debt. :)

Comment: need solution for IOS7

Comment: Not an ideal solution. Because the resizing takes place after presenting, it means that if you present with the animation flag YES, the user sees an incorrectly sized UIModalPresentationFormSheet animating in - most likely with misaligned content - followed by a "snap" as the completion block alters the superview size.

Comment: @Max Have you actually observed the "snap" after animation?  I have never observed this while animating the presentation.

Comment: @Brody yes have seen it. I mean it makes sense that it would happen as there's a frame change at the end of the animation. So you get the default form sheet size and animation - takes a split second - that then completes at which point there is an instant frame change. I'd guess the only way around it would be a custom view controller animation.

Comment: @Max I am observing the frame change is updating the animation  targets.  The presented view is animated into view to the appropriate frame location AND dimensions.  I just updated that answer for iOS 7, that may have been the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Brody But this solution seems not work in iOS8. My viewcontroller is enclosed inside a nav controller.It worked till iOS7.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a method that works on **iOS7** as well as iOS5 and iOS6: (arc)

```
-(void)presentController:(UIViewController*)controller fromRootController:(UIViewController*)rootController withSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [rootController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        nav.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        nav.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    }
    else
    {
        nav.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me on iOS 7, thank you. I'm getting a deprecation warning on `[rootController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];` stating that `presentModalViewController` is no longer supported as of iOS 6. I think the new method is `presentViewController`. Thanks again, nice work.

Comment: Working solution for changing the size under both iOS versions.

Comment: if the new size larger than the old one and I have clickable items in that area, they will not be clickable anymore... How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 12):

As of iOS7 you can simply do

```
composeTweetController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(380.0, 550.0);
```

Comment: This is the right approach. Even in the documentation it states: "To provide a custom content size, use the modal view controller’s preferredContentSize property."

Answer (score 11):

```
composeTweetController = [[ComposeTweet alloc] initWithNibName:@"ComposeTweet" bundle:nil];
composeTweetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:composeTweetController animated:TRUE];
//if you want to change its size but the view will remain centerd on the screen in both portrait and landscape then:
composeTweetViewController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
//or if you want to change it's position also, then:
composeTweetViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
```

Comment: I think you can just set `frame` __or__ `bounds` & `center`

Answer (score 4):

***Tested and works for iOS 6, using XCode 4.5***

I stumbled upon my answer after reading much of the tips on here:

1. In the `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method:

   ```
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //resize modal view
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 432, 680);
   ```
2. In the `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method:

   ```
   CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2);
   self.view.superview.center = centerPoint;
   ```

I tried to add the centering code in the same place as the resizing code, but that did not work.  For some reason, it only works after the view has appeared on the screen.

I surmise that it has something to do with the way that UIModalPresentationFormSheet works, because when I was stepping through in the LLDB debugger, I noticed that there was a variable _formSheetSize that was still {540, 620}.  Go figure.

Comment: The problem with this solution is the sheet changing its center after transitionStyle is completed

Comment: @FedeCugliandolo - You are correct.  The above method only works if you use a cross fade transition style, or don't animate at all.  I ended up presenting with no animation, then using my own animation.

Comment: Does not work for me :( The form sheet has still the same size

Comment: On iOS7 UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical is bugged too! But using UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve works fine

Answer (score 4):

This will work with any `UIModalTransitionStyle`

```
@interface BaseDialog ()

@property(nonatomic,assign) CGRect origFrame;

@end

@implementation BaseDialog

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.origFrame=self.view.frame;
}
-(CGSize)formSheetSize{
    return self.origFrame.size;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Well done!

I would love to know the reason why this works though! :)

Comment: apple use _formSheetSize in layout calculation. I am override for real size; real size i take from xib frame at load time;

Comment: Thanks! How did you find the class method / property formSheetSize ? Private headers?

Comment: stay on presentViewController:animated:comletion and inspect UIViewController in debugger. I am use intuition method :)

Comment: Wow, that's some smart 'hacking' kudos! I didn't even know you could do that! Write a tutorial blog post??? :)

Comment: it's hard to me to write tutorial. I am don't speak english, only read  and write 2-3 linked words. Where people write tutorials here?

Answer (score 4):

Following first code is how to present your model view controller

```
 composeTweetController = [[ComposeTweet alloc] initWithNibName:@"ComposeTweet" bundle:nil];
    composeTweetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:composeTweetController];
    navigationController.delegate = self;   
    [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

And In your ComposeTweet controller class

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 self.navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,500,400);
}
```

Comment: +1 - This is the only solution I could find that would respect the x,y coordinates you set.

Answer (score 3):

**iOS 7**

So the approach of setting the superview's frame or bounds doesn't work anymore on iOS 7 (for UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical). You can, however, now set the background color of the superview to clear and then change the frame of the modal view controller how you see fit.

So in iOS 7 you will want to:

1. present the view controller (presentation mode: UIModalPresentationFormSheet)
2. set view controller superview background color to clear
3. change frame of view controller as desired (perhaps making it smaller and then centering it in superview)

Comment: Centring the view within the superview is not required. Simply setting the bounds (after `-presentViewController:animated:completionHandler`) to `(0, 0, width, height)` causes it to automatically centre itself.

Comment: Setting the bounds worked fine for me without using the background color also. (My view controller is in a navigation controller.  Not sure if that matters here.)

Answer (score 2):

I got a full screen modal view from `UIPresentationFormSheet` with just this line:

```
modalViewController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748);
```

Answer (score 2):

@bdrobert sadly your nice solution does not work anymore on **iOS6** - the container keeps the original size even though the new viewcontroller is embedded with the custom size.

You probably need to use the containment API introduced in **iOS5**, but you need to add a dimmed background on your own, fetching all touch events for that area.

Comment: @Austin: I have used the containment API recently, but not for this purpose. For me going back to the original size is acceptable.

Comment: This is the best solution I see here. Modifying a view's superview's size, whether it be by changing the bounds or the frame, is just asking for trouble. It assumes implementation-specific knowledge of bits of the view hierarchy that you do not control.

Answer (score 0):

On change of orientation, this code work perfect....

settingViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

```
    [self presentViewController:settingViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    settingViewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 700);

    UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = [self getDeviceOrientation];

    if(currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
            CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2);
            settingViewController.view.superview.center = centerPoint;
    }
    else
    {
        CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2);
        settingViewController.view.superview.center = centerPoint;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern ios13 way:

use popover (formsheet and page ignore preferredContentSize)

then set or override `preferredContentSize` aka Ed Pilowat & Co

Answer (score -4):

The view size is fixed. You will have to implement things yourself if you want something different.

Comment: It's not incorrect and it is not at odds with your answer. Modifying the view controller's view's superview's frame counts as "something different", in my book.