# 2nd uitextfield in modal view not taking keyboard input

Tags: ipad, keyboard, uitextfield, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller

I am presenting my modal view using UIModalPresentationFormSheet and I am aware some have had issues resigning first responder and dimissing the keyboard in the past, but my issue is that the second textfield I pick I can't input text.  This is hapenning in iPad simulator 4.3.

This happens if I select the second uitextfield while the keyboard of the first textfield is still visible.  The cursor will move to the second textfield, but I am unable to edit it.  Most of the time I am unable to click the bottom right button which would dismiss the keyboard in iPad, but if it works, I can then select the second textfield and be able to edit it.

Has anyone encountered these issues before?

I am also implementing

```
-(BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal { return NO }
```

Even though this is not a solution it is a workaround.  Basically you use a pagesheet instead of form, and resize it.

[UIModalPresentationFormSheet resizing view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266581/uimodalpresentationformsheet-resizing-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this is not a solution it is a workaround. Basically you use a pagesheet instead of form, and resize it.

[UIModalPresentationFormSheet resizing view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266581/uimodalpresentationformsheet-resizing-view)

Comment: What do you mean by use a `pagesheet instead of form`? In the link you posted he answers it with UIModalPresentationFormSheet.