# With UIPresentationFormSheet, why doesn't my view move above the keyboard when it is up?

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

Apple says:

> UIModalPresentationFormSheet
>   The width and height of the presented view are smaller than those of the screen and the view is centered on the screen. **If the device is in a landscape orientation and the keyboard is visible, the position of the view is adjusted upward so that the view remains visible.** All uncovered areas are dimmed to prevent the user from interacting with them.

But my view doesn't move up when the keyboard is visible. I basically want to present a textview modally above the keyboard so the user can enter text and then hit send (in a nav bar button on the presented view.)

My presenting view is a `UISplitViewController` (not one of its children) and I'm presenting `UINavigationController` who's top view controller is basically a `UITextView`. Rotation works, but the presented view is overlapped by the keyboard in both orientations.

I found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457947/how-to-resize-a-uipresentationformsheet) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266581/uimodalpresentationformsheet-resizing-view) [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372333/ipad-keyboard-will-not-dismiss-if-modal-view-controller-presentation-style-is-ui/4455505#4455505) how to resize the presented view in this case, which is nice, but I don't want to have to make assumptions by resizing manually in the presenter or in the presented view. It seems like it should just pick a decent (undocumented) size just move it up automatically when the keyboard shows.

My presenting code looks like this:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc] autorelease];
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self.splitViewController presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was finishing up my question, I realized I was calling `becomeFirstResponder` on my UITextView in `viewWillAppear`. If you change it to `viewDidAppear` it will work, which makes sense.

Comment: I also found that if I use becomeFirstResponder even in viewDidAppear, I'd get undesirable effect. For example, in landscape mode the modal view would be incorrectly centered.  To circumvent the problem, invoke becomeFirstResponder within dispatch_async().