# On iPad, how to prevent the modal view from moving up upon keyboard presenting?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, modal-dialog

On iPad, I have a text field in the modal; when I tap on the text field to bring up keyboard, the whole modal view will move up, to have the least area covered by keyboard.

I don't want this behavior, because my text field will not be covered by keyboard anyway. How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932595/with-uipresentationformsheet-why-doesnt-my-view-move-above-the-keyboard-when-i

Comment: you can try this https://gist.github.com/Johnykutty/dc753461af32c0c528655bb062847147

Answer (score 0):

As a fall back, you could make your own window, and add your view to it, rather than put your view in an Apple managed modal view.

Answer (score 0):

For this follow this scenario..

add some **tag** to the **textfield**..then in **-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView** method give condition like if the textfield tag is **not equal to your preDefined tag** than move the modal view to up..
I hope it will works..