# Difficulty centering view controller when presented as form sheet

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a view controller with its presentation style set to form sheet. However, when the view controller appears, **it is positioned to the right of the screen, not in the center.** I am not sure why this is happening, or what I should do. All of these coordinates are correct!

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(650, 550);

//custom init for ViewController so I can position stuff correctly
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithSize:size];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];

nav.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
nav.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```

[image]

Comment: Did you mess with the auto-rotation mechanism?  It looks like the sheet is positioned where it would be if the Sim was turned so the home button was on the right

Comment: @CodaFi No, I haven't. The app is running in portrait mode, and that's where the sheet is positioned. When I remove the last two lines of code (responsible for resizing the sheet and centering it), the sheet is centered, however it is not the size I want (650 x 550).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that whenever I remove the last two lines, I get what I assume to be the behavior that you are looking for.

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(650, 550);

//custom init for ViewController so I can position stuff correctly
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithSize:size];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

I'm not sure exactly what you were trying to do with those two lines, but without them the view is centered.

Comment: How do I size the view differently then? I want it to be 650 x 550.

Comment: Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972990/how-to-resize-a-modalviewcontroller-with-uimodalpresentationpagesheet

Comment: On iOS7 Beta 5 neither UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal or UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical appears to get the form sheets centered. Only UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve works.

Comment: Thanx Carols. You're right. I'm using Xcode 5 and iOS7 SDK final now. The problem is still there. I think it's a bug.

Comment: I have the same issue when trying to present a modal view controller with UIModalPresentationFormSheet with any transition style and call [self.firstTextfield becomeFirstResponder] in viewDidAppear...