# What kind of segue is used on the App Store app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, segue

I would like to segue to a view controller rather like what you see in that app store for iPad that pops up when you tap an app. It's rather like a popover, but it's not attached to a button. Right now I'm using a popover attached to a hidden button, but I don't like it because it has a pointer pointing to the hidden button. I feel like this is something obvious to want, but I can't find a predefined segue to do this. Do I have to write my own?

The VC that I want to load this way is also called elsewhere using a popover from an actual button, so I want to retain that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a view controller presented modally using the UIModalPresentationFormSheet presentation style.

Comment: Hmm. I tried that, and you may be right. I rejected that style for some reason that I can't remember. I think I'll revisit it.

Comment: Ah, I remember now. It was the problem of sizing. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266581/uimodalpresentationformsheet-resizing-view) seems to answer that question.

Comment: never mind. That's not why I rejected it. I rejected it because I don't want a dismiss button. It should be dismissed by tapping an area next to the presented VC, just like with a popover.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `popoverBackgroundViewClass` to customise the popover display and remove the arrow. Your class needs to be a subclass of `UIPopoverBackgroundView`.