# How to resize view in XIB?

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface

I'm trying to follow these instructions with Xcode 4, but am unable to resize the xib. Does anyone know how? ( The width and height cannot be clicked upon ) Also there is no UITableViewController so I just used UIViewController.

EDIT - My goal is actually not to use the popover controller, I simply want to create a modal login dialog following the example here: [How to resize a UIModalPresentationFormSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457947/how-to-resize-a-uipresentationformsheet/4271364#4271364)  and am trying to make the view controller 300x400

> A popover controller has to have a
>   view controller inside of it. So we
>   need to create a new view controller.
>   Go to File > New File > Cocoa Touch
>   Classes > UIViewController >
>   UITableViewController subclass >> With
>   XIB for UI >> Targeted for iPad. Name
>   it OptionsViewController. Drag your
>   viewcontroller.h and viewcontroller.m
>   files into the classes group and the
>   new XIB into the resources group.
>
> Open the XIB and go to the Size
>   inspector. Change the width and height
>   properties to 250 and 300. Save your
>   file and close interface builder.

Answer (score 48):

It appears that in Xcode 4.5+, just to be annoying: Apple changed this again.

Instead, you now have to:

1. select the viewcontroler
2. select the "size" dropdown
3. set it to "Freeform"

...which removes their "block" on editing the size fields.

(this is pretty close to how I expected it to work in the first place, but I have to say it's not easy to find - you have to edit a different value on a different screen (with no help from Apple), in order to un-break the edit field on the correct screen. Not good design!)

Answer (score 35):

Interface Builder (and the IB equivalent in Xcode 4) won't let you change the size (or autosizing attributes) of a top-level view when any Simulated User Interface Elements are enabled.

Select your view, and in the View Attributes inspector set Status Bar, Top Bar, and Bottom Bar to Unspecified.  You should then be able to change the size.

Comment: perfect! i did not know that, was always freaking around in the xml of the xib

Comment: Thanks for this!  It's also worth noting that you can turn the simulated UI back on after resizing your view.

Comment: Don't forget to set size to None.

Answer (score 6):

In swift 4.2 interface builder won't let you change the size

click on the view and open the attribute inspector and change top, bottom bar to none and size to freeform. Now you are good to go for the change in size.

[image]