# How can I use UIModalPresentationFormSheet with NavigationController in iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4

I want to use UIModalPresentationFormSheet in my app. But i'm using navigation controller. So when i writes following code it is not responding me. What should i do ?

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with the below sample working code.

```
MyModalViewController *targetController = [[[MyModalViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 

targetController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
targetController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; //transition shouldn't matter 
[self presentModalViewController:targetController animated:YES];

targetController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);//it's important to do this after 

presentModalViewController targetController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```

Taken from -->

[How to resize a UIModalPresentationFormSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457947/how-to-resize-a-uipresentationformsheet/4271364#4271364)

Comment: You might want to indicate that this was copied from bdrobert's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457947/how-to-resize-a-uipresentationformsheet/4271364#4271364

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
 // assume controller is UIViewController.
 controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

Then

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, because the other one is for changing the default size.