# What is the exact size of UIModalPresentationFormSheet in iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, interface-builder, size

I am using following code for displaying a Screen/View Controller.

```
SearchParams *nxt=[[SearchParams alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchParams" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *nvc=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nxt];

nvc.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self.preLCtr.preCinescape_iPadViewController presentModalViewController:nvc animated:YES];
```

I am not sure about the size of PesentationSheet. I tried to take screenshots & take dimentions/size. But its not the exact solution.

Question : What is the exact size of Present-Modal-Sheet in iPad ?

Comment: According to the screen-shot taken, it is 545 × 625 pixels. Is it the correct one ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491951/what-exactly-is-the-height-of-modalpresentationstyle-formsheet-on-ipad You can find it here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIModalPresentationFormSheet) the size could change depending on the available screen size:

> The width and height of the presented view are smaller than those of the screen and the view is centered on the screen. If the device is in a landscape orientation and the keyboard is visible, the position of the view is adjusted upward so that the view remains visible. All uncovered areas are dimmed to prevent the user from interacting with them.

Maybe in the viewcontroller that is loaded to the FormSheet you can determine the view size at runtime by using: `self.view.bounds;`

If you need to resize the FormSheet i saw some answers on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457947/how-to-resize-a-uipresentationformsheet/4271364#4271364)

Answer (score 23):

This is what I found for the current (iPad 3) iO6 dimensions:

`BOUNDS: 540.000000, 620.000000` - Portrait-no-keyboard.

But you shouldn't use this for any code. Follow the correct answer.

Comment: It does seem bad to do this, but I wanted to recreate the form sheet size with a custom presentation controller and... it does seem to be a fixed 540x620. I tested a few different iPads and orientations and it never changes.

Answer (score 12):

If you're adjusting a freeform view controller so that you can get the aspect right for a modal transition with form sheet presentation style, note that there is a `Form Sheet` option under the Size dropdown in the Size Inspector. I didn't notice this at first.

[image]

Comment: How do you choose a custom form sheet size - no matter what I try - I get a standard form sheet?

Answer (score 3):

I checked different orientation and also in multi window mode, the default size is

`width: 540, height: 620`.

And below is the screenshot from Reveal.

[image]

Comment: Shout out to Reveal!