# Page sheet modal size for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

Does anyone know the dimensions (pixels) of page sheet size modal for iPad? I found the size for the Form sheet (540x620px) here: [What is the exact size of UIModalPresentationFormSheet in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490947/what-is-the-exact-size-of-uimodalpresentationformsheet-in-ipad)

but I could not find the Page Sheet dimensions. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Portrait: `768x1004`

Landscape: `768x748`

[image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts.html  Looks like it's full screen in portrait mode and in landscape mode it is the width of the portrait mode's height (768px). so that it goes full screen when the user tilts the iPad. still not sure on the height in Landscape but it looks like it doesn't go all the way to the top.