# What exactly is the height of modalPresentationStyle - FormSheet on iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller

What exactly is the height of modalPresentationStyle - FormSheet on iPad? I wrote a line of code to get the height of self.view like this:

```
println("Height - modalPresentationStyle FormSheet: \(self.view.frame.size.height)")
```

I got these two results after testing:

**Without Formsheet on ModalViewController**, height at **1024.0**

**With Formsheet on modalPresentationStyle**, height at **1024.0**  which is wrong because the height is supposed to be less than 1024.0

Any idea what is wrong with it? I need to get the right height from self.view.frame.size.height with formsheet because I need to write the  formula somewhere in the code. I don't need to change the size of formsheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't implement your `println` inside `viewDidLoad` but inside `viewDidAppear`.

The following class that is presented in the Storyboard with *Segue: Present Modally* and *Presentation: Form Sheet* gives different results for the same `println` when called in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(view.frame) // (0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 1024.0)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        println(view.frame) // (0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 1024.0)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        println(view.frame) // (0.0, 0.0, 540.0, 620.0) // Correct values
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I didn't even think to implement my `println` inside `viewDidAppear` . Now It is working so well. Thanks again!

Comment: You are great. Thank you.