# UINavigationController size on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am having problems adjusting the size of the UINavigationController on iPad (iOS 4.3.5). On the tablet's large screen it appears as a window with the background of fullscreen view dimmed, however I want to adjust the width of that window (to be the same size as iPhone Retina display).

```
SettingsViewController *settingsController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsController];

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

SettingsViewController contains a UITableView and with the default width of the UINavigationController window it looks too wide, so I need to either make the window narrower or at least add some padding to the underlying UITableView, so that the rows are not as wide.

Any solutions/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: DONOT present the navigationController as a modalviewcontroller.  Bad things will happen.  Call [window addSubview:self.navController.view];

Comment: That would make the view appear fullscreen - I want it to be displayed in a window (on iPad)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it in another thread [How to resize a UIModalPresentationFormSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457947/how-to-resize-a-uipresentationformsheet).

I just needed to set the modalPresentationStyle on the navController to UIModalPresentationFormSheet and after presenting it, modify the superview frame size and center.

```
SettingsViewController *settingsController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsController];
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

navController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
navController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
```