# How can I change size when showing a modal view controller using storyboard?

Tags: ios5, storyboard, modalviewcontroller

Using storyboard, I create a transition to another view controller using modal style and form sheet presentation. But always has the same size.

How can I change this view controller size using storyboard?
I found some code that almost work, but I never get mu modal view controller centered.
[How to resize a UIModalPresentationFormSheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457947/how-to-resize-a-uipresentationformsheet/4271364#4271364)
Note that I use Storyboard and that code is not for storyboard.

Do you have any idea or suggestion?

By the way, it seems prepareForSegue os called BEFORE viewDidLoad, is this normal?

Thanks a lot for replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it's a little late.

I've implemented it before.. I've managed to get UIPresentationFormSheet centered.
Here's my code..

```
[detailView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[detailView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];    
[self presentModalViewController:detailView animated:YES];
detailView.view.superview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
float heightOfFrame = 200.0f;
float widthOfFrame= 400.0f;
detailView.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(
    self.view.superview.center.x - (widthOfFrame/2),                                         
    self.view.superview.center.y - (heightOfFrame/2),
    widthOfFrame,
    heightOfFrame
);
```

Hope I've helped you in some ways.

Regards, Steve

Comment: Thanks for reply. What do you think about using bounds? And, do you have problems when presented view is a navigation controller? It seems these hacks doesn't work when using navigation controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently and was able to change the size of the form sheet view using this property:

[image]