# Issue with Modal View Controller Size

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have a View Controller that I present modally using the following code :

```
about.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;             
[self presentModalViewController:about animated:NO];

about.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake( about.view.superview.frame.origin.x+110,
                                         about.view.superview.frame.origin.y-0,
                                         320.0f,
                                         460.0f
                                        );
```

Now, If I present another view controller modally using the same code and similar size, everything works fine.

However, if I present a view controller modally that has the full screen size then, if I hit back (dismiss the last View Controller), the original View Controller will increase in size. The increases size is the regular size of UIModalPresentationFormSheet.

In other words: present ViewController A modally as mentioned above, then present another ViewController B from ViewController A modally. Now if B is full screen and we close it to go back to ViewController A, A will now be resized to the default frame size.
I am not sure how to fix this issue. Can anyone kindly suggest a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure Why do you move the superview of the modal view. But it seem you use the code above to present B in A? Thus, A will be B's superview and its size will be set to 320, 460. I guess that is the reason for A's resizing.

Comment: @Selkie : the decision to act on the superview of the modal view was based on   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457947/how-to-resize-a-uipresentationformsheet/4271364#4271364   (you need to do this in order to change the frame of a Modal VC with PresentationFormSheet.

Comment: @Selkie : Also, I am resizing to (320,460), why would it go to something liek (560,650) (not exact values).