# Custom size for Modal View loaded with Form Sheet presentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipresentationcontroller

I'm trying to load a UIViewController in iPad with Form Sheet presentation. The problem is the size of this new view, i put the size values in the IBuilder but the modal view take a fixed value.

Also i tried to make this in prepareForSegue like this:

```
HelpViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
viewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

But don't work, any help? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, i got set a custom size in viewWillAppear method of the modal view using:

[self.view.superview setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];

But now, the window is not centered with the layout

Comment: [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457947/how-to-resize-a-uipresentationformsheet/4271364#4271364)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787946/ios8-unable-to-re-size-the-modal-form-sheet-after-changing-the-orientation

Check this link you can get the solution

Answer (score 86):

For iOS 8, use:

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

I've placed this in `viewDidLoad`.

## **Swift 3**

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
```

Comment: How do you set this in Interface Builder?

Comment: in IOS 8 migration, how can i change the position?

Comment: `preferredContentSize` is introduced in iOS 7

Comment: Works for iOS9+ also

Comment: For this to work, I had to use .modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet

Comment: It's not working for me. After presenting the xib as formsheet, I am changing the content size after some user inputs. It's not getting changed, but if I rotate the screen it's reflecting. Xcode 10 and iOS 12.1

Comment: Worked for me (iOS 13), using .modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet and view controller in storyboard with size Freeform

Answer (score 23):

In Attributes inspector check `Use Preferred Explicit Size`

[image]

Comment: This is working if you set the Presentation to Form Sheet.

Comment: How can I decrease the transparency black when presenting as form sheet?

Answer (score 15):

Setting `preferredContentSize` didn't work for me on iOS 11 for example when presenting `EKEventEditViewController`.

It works only if I override getter of `preferredContentSize`. Something like this:

```
private class CLEventEditViewController: EKEventEditViewController {
    override var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
        get {
            if let fullSize = self.presentingViewController?.view.bounds.size {
                return CGSize(width: fullSize.width * 0.5,
                              height: fullSize.height * 0.75)
            }
            return super.preferredContentSize
        }
        set {
            super.preferredContentSize = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Eliminate your optional by using let fullSize = super.preferredContentSize

Answer (score 11):

EDIT

Use `preferredContentSize`.

**Old**

You can try this for show view in center

```
HelpViewController * viewController = [[[HelpViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
viewController.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:^{
    viewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    viewController.view.superview.center = self.view.center;
}];
```

Comment: At least in iOS 7 this doesn't work - it shows it presenting if full size, and then afterwards it shrinks it. As evidenced by the 'completion' block.

Comment: To perform this on iOS7 take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19026882/1363634

Answer (score 3):

My solution is based heavily on other solutions posted here but since I had to try many different things to get it to actually work I am posting it.  Mine is for iOS 10 with Swift 3.1 in a portrait-mode only app. (Untested in landscape mode)  The goal of my solution was to display a modal that was smaller than the presenting view, and such that I could see the presenting view in the background.

I had to configure the UIViewController properly in Interface Builder or my code wouldn't work.  Here are my settings.  I found my solution to work with both `Cross Dissolve` and `Cover Vertical` transition styles.  I think the key for me in IB was the `Over Full Screen` for Presentation - it didn't appear to work with some other values for this setting.

[image: IB Settings]

Here is the code in the UIViewController I want to present modally.  Then I just call it using `present(_:animated:completion:)` elsewhere.  Also, in the VC I will present modally, I have a bool, `didLayout` initialized as `false`:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        if !didLayout {

            let width:CGFloat = self.view.bounds.width * 0.95 //modify this constant to change the amount of the screen occupied by the modal
            let height:CGFloat = width * 1.618 //golden ratio

            self.view.superview!.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.15) //slightly dim the background to focus on the modal
            let screen = self.view.superview!.bounds
            let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
            let x = (screen.size.width - frame.size.width) * 0.5
            let y = (screen.size.height - frame.size.height) * 0.5
            let mainFrame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)

            self.view.frame = mainFrame

            didLayout = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's important to note that `Over Full Screen` is a different presentation style than `Form Sheet`, so even if your answer may actually help people who are better served using `Over Full Screen` , the question is specifically addressing the latter. For a list of all the modal presentation style options, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like @Stuart Campbell and @Viruss mca.

**Edited**

After @Erich's comment, I rewrote it to run in iOS 8 too. Below is the code:

```
  HelpViewController * viewController = [[[HelpViewController alloc] init]];
  viewController.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
  [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

--

```
//HelpViewController.m

- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    if (!didLayout) {
        [self layout];
        didLayout = YES;
    }
}
- (void) layout{
    self.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    CGRect screen = self.view.superview.bounds;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, <width>, <height>);
    float x = (screen.size.width - frame.size.width)*.5f;
    float y = (screen.size.height - frame.size.height)*.5f;
    frame = CGRectMake(x, y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

    self.view.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: Creating problem in orientation changes

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a view in XIB that is set as a modally presented view for a view controller. A very easy way to fix this is to simply change the Size Metrics to **Freeform** (See Figure 1.0) and resize the view to whatever you want it to be. The view will appear with these metrics when loaded modaly.

Setting Preferred Content Size didn't help in my case but this fixed my issue. It

Figure 1.0:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got around this problem by putting my content inside a view in the modal vc. Then setting the vc background transparent and in viewWillAppear settings the formsheet background transparent. This means you only see the content.

```
// In Modal vc
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

I set it all from storyboard and used a segue, if using code you would need to set this also.

```
parentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
```

Answer (score 1):

Erich's post worked for me, but on iOS 10 with Swift 3, I had to use:

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width, height)
```

I too placed it in `viewdidload`

Also, like avdyushin said, I had to check the `Use Preferred Explicit Size` box.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, You should resize superview's frame after presenting it.

```
HelpViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
viewController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
```