# preferredContentSize not working in ios 7?

Tags: ios, size, frame

I am using `modalPresentationStyle` of type `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` to show my view.I want specific size of the view so using `preferredContentSize` which working in `iOS 8` and showing exact how I wanted but same breaks for `iOS 7` it's come as full sheet.View size changed.

[image]

Where as I wanted like below image

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below conditional code for iOS 8.x and iOS 7

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) 
{
    modalController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(frameSize.x, frameSize.y); 
}
else 
{
    modalController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake((screenWidth - frameSize.x)/2, (screenHeight - frameSize.y)/2, frameSize.x, frameSize.y);

}
```

Hope this will help you.