# iOS8 unable to re-size the modal form sheet after changing the orientation

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8

> Actually what i am doing is on iPad i am presenting the modal form
>   sheet with my own size (520 X 400). It was working fine at first time.
>   Then when i do rotate (portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait)
>   my modal form sheet changed to ios default size. Also, i was not able
>   to change the modal form sheet size again by programatically. Since,
>   once the orientation changed ios making my (520X400) modal form sheet
>   to its default size. Any idea how to fix this?.

[image: screenshot when i am presenting my modal at first time]

[image: screenshot when i changed the device orientation]

Note:

> When i ran on ios7 device i not am seeing any issue with the
>   following code. If any thing wrong with my code then please indicate
>   me. Since i do not know what's wrong with ios8

**Here is the code that was i used to change the modal form sheet size:**

```
self.navigationController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(200, 220, 400, 605);
```

Answer (score 16):

finally i figure out a way how to resolve the above one.

Here my solution:

on ios8 just setting the following property to your modal view will resolve the issue

in view did load:

```
CGRect rect = self.navigationController.view.superview.bounds;
rect.size.width = 605;
rect.size.height = 350;
self.navigationController.view.superview.bounds = rect;
self.navigationController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(605, 350);
```

before presenting your modal view

```
your_modal_view.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(540.0f, 620.0f) //what ever the size you want
```

I hope this helps

Comment: so if you add the preferredContentSize then it works, sweet! thanks