# change size View pop up (form sheet) swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, viewcontroller

Is possible to change size of pop up view? I couldn't find how to change size of UIView.
I want to change height of my pop up.

Comment: Please Describe more

Comment: post your code of popping view .

Comment: Thank you for response, i already had the solution based on iOS Hitler's comment.
My question similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518175/custom-size-for-modal-view-loaded-with-form-sheet-presentation but i asked it in swift. But i figured there's no difference evein it in obj-c or swift it can use `self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);` in the `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yourviewcontroller.popoverContentSize` will help you to adjust the height

eg:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(325, 75);
popoverController.popoverContentSize = size;
```

Comment: thank you for the solution.. it's work!