# PresentViewController without fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Quick question again. When I use `presentViewController` to present a new viewcontroller on top of my current one it is full screen. How do I get it to present a specific size? Or should I use another method.

**Code:**

```
- (IBAction)showProfile:(id)sender {
ProfileView *profileTop = [[ProfileView alloc] init];
profileTop.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:profileTop animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Did you try positioning and sizing self.view.frame within the presented view controller accordingly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize a UIPresentationFormSheet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457947/how-to-resize-a-uipresentationformsheet)

Comment: Why are you not using addsubview instead of modal view ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are developing an app for `iPad` then you can make use of viewController's `modalPresentationStyle` property, You need to set for presenting viewController.

It has 4 values for that variable.

```
UIModalPresentationFullScreen = 0,
UIModalPresentationPageSheet,
UIModalPresentationFormSheet,
UIModalPresentationCurrentContext
```

You can select which one suites you the best.

Comment: I did read about this but I had no idea how to implement it..can you elaborate on your code?

Comment: Sure, Please add this line `profileTop.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;` before presenting to make the ProfileView aligned to center.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was going for..but it's actually a really smooth animation. I guess im gonna have to read up on the UIModalPresentations

Comment: I actually think im gonna use this instead of the idea I had, thanks! How would you remove the field when tapping outside of it?

Comment: If you want to achieve nice animation you can make use of `modalTransitionStyle` try this also, its really cool :)

Comment: May be you can try this link for dismiss,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623417/iphone-sdk-dismissing-modal-viewcontrollers-on-ipad-by-clicking-outside-of-it   I have not tried it.

Comment: What a coincidence I was just reading that link haha. Did not figure it out yet but can't be that hard, thanks!

Comment: I did this but the modalvc presented is still full screen for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest doing a little more research, specifically in Apple's reference. Of note, there is this quote from the View Controller Programming Guide (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html):

> Presentation Styles for Modal Views
>
> For iPad apps, you can present content using several different styles. In iPhone apps, presented views always cover the visible portion of the window, but when running on an iPad, view controllers use the value in their modalPresentationStyle property to determine their appearance when presented. Different options for this property allow you to present the view controller so that it fills all or only part of the screen.

And specifically, on the API reference page for presentViewController (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:):

> On iPhone and iPod touch, the presented view is always full screen. On iPad, the presentation depends on the value in the modalPresentationStyle property.

Only the iPad appears to have any support for non-fullscreen modals.

Comment: @Tarayaa You should change the tags then.

Answer (score 4):

On iPad you can just use:

```
[viewcontroller setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
```

example:

```
LoginDialogViewController * login_dialog = [[LoginDialogViewController alloc] init];
[login_dialog setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[self presentViewController:login_dialog animated:true completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code. Then adjust the view size in the xib file. See the below figure
[image: size inspector]