# ios7 presentviewcontroller cannot set frame

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have used this code in iOS 6 and I can present another view in the middle of main view. However, when I run in iOS 7, that presented view's origin is always at 0,0. How shall I do?

```
rect= CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width/2)-300,(self.view.bounds.size.height/2)-200,600,400);
self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:sVCiPad animated:YES completion:nil];
[sVCiPad.view setFrame:rect];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`.

**Instead of**

```
self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

**Try this**

```
sVCiPad.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

Comment: But I can't set frame. How shall I do? This code is not working in iOS 7.         sVCiPad.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 500);

Comment: I got solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457947/how-to-resize-a-uipresentationformsheet